# Get all nodes in apache ignite cluster

Tags: c#, .net, ignite

We are starting to use Apache Ignite for distributed memory purposes. Currently, I have a windows service that starts the nodes and attempts to connect to remote nodes listed in a database table. I have 2 VMs and when I start the service, it is able to start a local node on both VMs but when I call the IIgnite.GetCluster() method and try to get the nodes in the cluster, it only lists the local node and not the remote node.

Below is the code I have for instantiating and spitting out the nodes in the cluster.

Thanks for your help in advance.

```
var registeredIPs = systemStartupHelper.GetRegisteredInstances(); //This gets the IP for all known nodes
                var cfg = new IgniteConfiguration
                {
                    DiscoverySpi = new TcpDiscoverySpi
                    {
                        IpFinder = new TcpDiscoveryStaticIpFinder
                        {
                            Endpoints = registeredIPs
                        },
                        SocketTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3),
                        JoinTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
                        ForceServerMode = true,
                        ReconnectCount = 1
                    },
                    IncludedEventTypes = new Collection<int> { EventType.CacheObjectPut },
                    FailureDetectionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
                    NetworkTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),

                };
                cfg.IgniteInstanceName = "TestApacheIgnite";
                igniteNode = Ignition.Start(cfg);

                eventLog1.WriteEntry("Finished startup for detected Ignite nodes", EventLogEntryType.Information);
                for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                {
                    ICluster cluster = igniteNode.GetCluster();
                    ICollection<IClusterNode> nodes = cluster.GetNodes();
                    StringBuilder nodeInformation = new StringBuilder();
                    foreach (var item in nodes)
                    {
                        nodeInformation.AppendLine($"Node {string.Join(",", item.HostNames)}: Attributes {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item.Attributes)}");
                    }
                    eventLog1.WriteEntry(nodeInformation.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Information);
                    Task.Delay(15000).Wait();
                }
```

**EDIT**
Here are the logs from both nodes. You can see from the logs that they only seem themselves and not the other instance. There should be two sets of nodes per instance.

Node 1

Node Node1.dev.local: Attributes {"awt.toolkit":"sun.awt.windows.WToolkit","h2.objectCacheMaxPerElementSize":"0","java.specification.version":"1.8","sun.cpu.isalist":"amd64","sun.jnu.encoding":"Cp1252","ALLUSERSPROFILE":"C:\ProgramData","org.apache.ignite.rest.tcp.host.names":["EC2AMAZ-VQ7V7I9.dev.local"],"sun.arch.data.model":"64","SystemDrive":"C:","org.apache.ignite.build.ver":"2.8.1","org.apache.ignite.rebalance.pool.size":4,"java.vendor.url":"http://java.oracle.com/","TcpCommunicationSpi.comm.tcp.host.names":["EC2AMAZ-VQ7V7I9.dev.local"],"USERNAME":"dxt","h2.serializeJavaObject":"false","org.apache.ignite.update.notifier.enabled":true,"ProgramFiles(x86)":"C:\Program Files (x86)","sun.boot.library.path":"C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.265.01-hotspot\jre\bin","PATHEXT":".COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC","DriverData":"C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData","java.specification.vendor":"Oracle Corporation","java.home":"C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.265.01-hotspot\jre","file.separator":"\","line.separator":"\r\n","org.apache.ignite.data.streamer.pool.size":8,"HOMEPATH":"\Users\DXT","org.apache.ignite.phy.ram":8589524992,"java.vm.specification.vendor":"Oracle Corporation","java.specification.name":"Java Platform API Specification","PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER":"Intel64 Family 6 Model 79 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel","ProgramFiles":"C:\Program Files","PUBLIC":"C:\Users\Public","windir":"C:\Windows","org.apache.ignite.peer.classloading.enabled":false,"org.apache.ignite.lang.rt":"Java Platform API Specification ver. 1.8","org.apache.ignite.features":"+10M","sun.boot.class.path":"C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.265.01-hotspot\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.265.01-hotspot\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.265.01-hotspot\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.265.01-hotspot\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.265.01-hotspot\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.265.01-hotspot\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.265.01-hotspot\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.265.01-hotspot\jre\classes","user.script":"","java.util.logging.config.file":"C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release\Release\config\java.util.logging.properties","sun.management.compiler":"HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers","JAVA_HOME":"C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.265.01-hotspot\jre","java.runtime.version":"1.8.0_265-b01","user.name":"dxt","org.apache.ignite.marshaller.utf8SerializationVer2":false,"org.apache.ignite.data.regions.offheap.size":1717904998,"APPDATA":"C:\Users\DXT\AppData\Roaming","file.encoding":"UTF-8","org.apache.ignite.macs":"0280B3ED7B55","org.apache.ignite.marshaller.compactFooter":true,"NoopCollisionSpi.org.apache.ignite.spi.class":"org.apache.ignite.spi.collision.noop.NoopCollisionSpi","Path":"C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.265.01-hotspot\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Amazon\cfn-bootstrap\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;C:\Users\DXT\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps","org.apache.ignite.user.name":"dxt","org.apache.ignite.rest.tcp.port":11211,"java.io.tmpdir":"C:\Users\DXT\AppData\Local\Temp\","org.apache.ignite.jit.name":"HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers","java.version":"1.8.0_265","COMPUTERNAME":"EC2AMAZ-VQ7V7I9","java.vm.specification.name":"Java Virtual Machine Specification","java.awt.printerjob":"sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob","ComSpec":"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe","sun.os.patch.level":"","NoopCheckpointSpi.org.apache.ignite.spi.class":"org.apache.ignite.spi.checkpoint.noop.NoopCheckpointSpi","java.library.path":"C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release\Release;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.265.01-hotspot\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Amazon\cfn-bootstrap\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;C:\Users\DXT\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;.","TcpCommunicationSpi.comm.tcp.addrs":["10.239.102.10","0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1","127.0.0.1"],"TcpCommunicationSpi.comm.shmem.tcp.port":null,"java.vendor":"AdoptOpenJDK","HOMEDRIVE":"C:","org.apache.ignite.jvm.args":"@@@-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8@@@-Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release\Release\config\java.util.logging.properties","org.apache.ignite.data.storage.config":"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","sun.io.unicode.encoding":"UnicodeLittle","NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS":"2","TcpDiscoverySpi.org.apache.ignite.spi.class":"org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi","http.strictPostRedirect":"true","h2.optimizeTwoEquals":"false","USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE":"dev","sun.desktop":"windows","PROCESSOR_LEVEL":"6","file.encoding.pkg":"sun.io","java.class.path":"C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release\Release\libs\cache-api-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release\Release\libs\commons-codec-1.11.jar;C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release\Release\libs\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release\Release\libs\h2-1.4.197.jar;C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release\Release\libs\ignite-core-2.8.1.jar;C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release\Release\libs\ignite-indexing-2.8.1.jar;C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release\Release\libs\ignite-shmem-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release\Release\libs\ignite-spring-2.8.1.jar;C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release\Release\libs\lucene-analyzers-common-7.4.0.jar;C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release\Release\libs\lucene-core-7.4.0.jar;C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release\Release\libs\lucene-queryparser-7.4.0.jar;C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release\Release\libs\spring-aop-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release\Release\libs\spring-beans-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release\Release\libs\spring-context-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release\Release\libs\spring-core-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release\Release\libs\spring-expression-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release\Release\libs\spring-jdbc-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release\Release\libs\spring-tx-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar;","PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE":"AMD64","java.vm.vendor":"AdoptOpenJDK","PSModulePath":"%ProgramFiles%\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules;C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS Tools\PowerShell\","user.variant":"","user.timezone":"UTC","org.apache.ignite.cache.client":false,"os.name":"Windows Server 2019","java.vm.specification.version":"1.8","org.apache.ignite.cache.lateAffinity":true,"org.apache.ignite.consistency.check.skipped":false,"org.apache.ignite.platform":"dotnet","USERDNSDOMAIN":"DEV.LOCAL","user.country":"US","h2.dropRestrict":"false","NoopEventStorageSpi.org.apache.ignite.spi.class":"org.apache.ignite.spi.eventstorage.NoopEventStorageSpi","org.apache.ignite.consistent.id":"0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1,10.239.102.10,127.0.0.1:47500","org.apache.ignite.event.driven.service.processor.enabled":true,"sun.cpu.endian":"little","user.home":"C:\Users\DXT","user.language":"en","AlwaysFailoverSpi.gg:failover:maxattempts":5,"ProgramData":"C:\ProgramData","ProgramW6432":"C:\Program Files","org.apache.ignite.cache.validate.cache.requests":true,"h2.objectCache":"false","org.apache.ignite.build.date":"20200521","java.awt.graphicsenv":"sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment","org.apache.ignite.tx":{},"LOCALAPPDATA":"C:\Users\DXT\AppData\Local","org.apache.ignite.dynamic.cache.start.rollback.supported":true,"USERDOMAIN":"dev","TcpCommunicationSpi.comm.tcp.ext-addrs":null,"LOGONSERVER":"\\WIN-I952126Q8TK","org.apache.ignite.ips":"10.239.102.10, fe80:0:0:0:d52:4da8:688d:f6a%eth2","path.separator":";","os.version":"10.0","java.endorsed.dirs":"C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.265.01-hotspot\jre\lib\endorsed","org.apache.ignite.rest.tcp.addrs":["10.239.102.10","0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1","127.0.0.1"],"ERLANG_HOME":"C:\Program Files\erl-23.0","java.runtime.name":"OpenJDK Runtime Environment","org.apache.ignite.ignite.dep.mode":{},"java.vm.name":"OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM","org.apache.ignite.ignite.name":"DXTApacheIgnite","org.apache.ignite.authentication.enabled":false,"org.apache.ignite.jvm.pid":4624,"LocalDeploymentSpi.org.apache.ignite.spi.class":"org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.local.LocalDeploymentSpi","comm.direct.proto.ver":3,"TcpCommunicationSpi.org.apache.ignite.spi.class":"org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi","CommonProgramFiles":"C:\Program Files\Common Files","java.vendor.url.bug":"http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/","org.apache.ignite.rest.port.range":100,"org.apache.ignite.offheap.size":1822762598,"OS":"Windows_NT","org.apache.ignite.marshaller.useDefaultSUID":false,"user.dir":"C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release\Release","org.apache.ignite.restart.enabled":"false","os.arch":"amd64","PROCESSOR_REVISION":"4f01","CommonProgramW6432":"C:\Program Files\Common Files","AlwaysFailoverSpi.org.apache.ignite.spi.class":"org.apache.ignite.spi.failover.always.AlwaysFailoverSpi","TcpCommunicationSpi.comm.tcp.pairedConnection":false,"RoundRobinLoadBalancingSpi.org.apache.ignite.spi.class":"org.apache.ignite.spi.loadbalancing.roundrobin.RoundRobinLoadBalancingSpi","SystemRoot":"C:\Windows","TEMP":"C:\Users\DXT\AppData\Local\Temp","java.vm.info":"mixed mode","USERPROFILE":"C:\Users\DXT","java.vm.version":"25.265-b01","TMP":"C:\Users\DXT\AppData\Local\Temp","TcpCommunicationSpi.comm.tcp.port":47100,"clientListenerPort":10800,"CommonProgramFiles(x86)":"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files","java.ext.dirs":"C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.265.01-hotspot\jre\lib\ext;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\lib\ext","java.class.version":"52.0","org.apache.ignite.marshaller":"org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryMarshaller"}

Node 2

Node Node2.dev.local: Attributes {"awt.toolkit":"sun.awt.windows.WToolkit","h2.objectCacheMaxPerElementSize":"0","java.specification.version":"1.8","sun.cpu.isalist":"amd64","sun.jnu.encoding":"Cp1252","ALLUSERSPROFILE":"C:\ProgramData","org.apache.ignite.rest.tcp.host.names":["EC2AMAZ-86IDRFF.dev.local"],"sun.arch.data.model":"64","SystemDrive":"C:","org.apache.ignite.build.ver":"2.8.1","org.apache.ignite.rebalance.pool.size":4,"java.vendor.url":"http://java.oracle.com/","TcpCommunicationSpi.comm.tcp.host.names":["EC2AMAZ-86IDRFF.dev.local"],"USERNAME":"dxt","h2.serializeJavaObject":"false","org.apache.ignite.update.notifier.enabled":true,"ProgramFiles(x86)":"C:\Program Files (x86)","sun.boot.library.path":"C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.265.01-hotspot\jre\bin","PATHEXT":".COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC","DriverData":"C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData","java.specification.vendor":"Oracle Corporation","java.home":"C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.265.01-hotspot\jre","file.separator":"\","line.separator":"\r\n","org.apache.ignite.data.streamer.pool.size":8,"HOMEPATH":"\Users\DXT","org.apache.ignite.phy.ram":8589524992,"java.vm.specification.vendor":"Oracle Corporation","java.specification.name":"Java Platform API Specification","PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER":"Intel64 Family 6 Model 79 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel","ProgramFiles":"C:\Program Files","PUBLIC":"C:\Users\Public","windir":"C:\Windows","org.apache.ignite.peer.classloading.enabled":false,"org.apache.ignite.lang.rt":"Java Platform API Specification ver. 1.8","org.apache.ignite.features":"+10M","sun.boot.class.path":"C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.265.01-hotspot\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.265.01-hotspot\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.265.01-hotspot\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.265.01-hotspot\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.265.01-hotspot\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.265.01-hotspot\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.265.01-hotspot\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.265.01-hotspot\jre\classes","user.script":"","java.util.logging.config.file":"C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release\config\java.util.logging.properties","sun.management.compiler":"HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers","JAVA_HOME":"C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.265.01-hotspot\","java.runtime.version":"1.8.0_265-b01","user.name":"dxt","org.apache.ignite.marshaller.utf8SerializationVer2":false,"org.apache.ignite.data.regions.offheap.size":1717904998,"APPDATA":"C:\Users\DXT\AppData\Roaming","file.encoding":"UTF-8","org.apache.ignite.macs":"06DFFD580B33","org.apache.ignite.marshaller.compactFooter":true,"NoopCollisionSpi.org.apache.ignite.spi.class":"org.apache.ignite.spi.collision.noop.NoopCollisionSpi","Path":"C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.265.01-hotspot\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Amazon\cfn-bootstrap\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;C:\Users\DXT\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps","org.apache.ignite.user.name":"dxt","org.apache.ignite.rest.tcp.port":11211,"java.io.tmpdir":"C:\Users\DXT\AppData\Local\Temp\","org.apache.ignite.jit.name":"HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers","java.version":"1.8.0_265","COMPUTERNAME":"EC2AMAZ-86IDRFF","java.vm.specification.name":"Java Virtual Machine Specification","java.awt.printerjob":"sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob","ComSpec":"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe","sun.os.patch.level":"","NoopCheckpointSpi.org.apache.ignite.spi.class":"org.apache.ignite.spi.checkpoint.noop.NoopCheckpointSpi","java.library.path":"C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.265.01-hotspot\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Amazon\cfn-bootstrap\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;C:\Users\DXT\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;.","TcpCommunicationSpi.comm.tcp.addrs":["127.0.0.1","0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1","10.239.102.144"],"TcpCommunicationSpi.comm.shmem.tcp.port":null,"java.vendor":"AdoptOpenJDK","HOMEDRIVE":"C:","org.apache.ignite.jvm.args":"@@@-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8@@@-Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release\config\java.util.logging.properties","org.apache.ignite.data.storage.config":"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","sun.io.unicode.encoding":"UnicodeLittle","NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS":"2","TcpDiscoverySpi.org.apache.ignite.spi.class":"org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi","http.strictPostRedirect":"true","h2.optimizeTwoEquals":"false","USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE":"dev","sun.desktop":"windows","PROCESSOR_LEVEL":"6","file.encoding.pkg":"sun.io","java.class.path":"C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release\libs\cache-api-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release\libs\commons-codec-1.11.jar;C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release\libs\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release\libs\h2-1.4.197.jar;C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release\libs\ignite-core-2.8.1.jar;C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release\libs\ignite-indexing-2.8.1.jar;C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release\libs\ignite-shmem-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release\libs\ignite-spring-2.8.1.jar;C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release\libs\lucene-analyzers-common-7.4.0.jar;C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release\libs\lucene-core-7.4.0.jar;C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release\libs\lucene-queryparser-7.4.0.jar;C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release\libs\spring-aop-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release\libs\spring-beans-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release\libs\spring-context-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release\libs\spring-core-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release\libs\spring-expression-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release\libs\spring-jdbc-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release\libs\spring-tx-4.3.26.RELEASE.jar;","PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE":"AMD64","java.vm.vendor":"AdoptOpenJDK","PSModulePath":"%ProgramFiles%\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules;C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS Tools\PowerShell\","user.variant":"","user.timezone":"UTC","org.apache.ignite.cache.client":false,"os.name":"Windows Server 2019","java.vm.specification.version":"1.8","org.apache.ignite.cache.lateAffinity":true,"org.apache.ignite.consistency.check.skipped":false,"org.apache.ignite.platform":"dotnet","USERDNSDOMAIN":"DEV.LOCAL","user.country":"US","h2.dropRestrict":"false","NoopEventStorageSpi.org.apache.ignite.spi.class":"org.apache.ignite.spi.eventstorage.NoopEventStorageSpi","org.apache.ignite.consistent.id":"0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1,10.239.102.144,127.0.0.1:47500","org.apache.ignite.event.driven.service.processor.enabled":true,"sun.cpu.endian":"little","user.home":"C:\Users\DXT","user.language":"en","AlwaysFailoverSpi.gg:failover:maxattempts":5,"ProgramData":"C:\ProgramData","ProgramW6432":"C:\Program Files","org.apache.ignite.cache.validate.cache.requests":true,"h2.objectCache":"false","org.apache.ignite.build.date":"20200521","java.awt.graphicsenv":"sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment","org.apache.ignite.tx":{},"LOCALAPPDATA":"C:\Users\DXT\AppData\Local","org.apache.ignite.dynamic.cache.start.rollback.supported":true,"USERDOMAIN":"dev","TcpCommunicationSpi.comm.tcp.ext-addrs":null,"LOGONSERVER":"\\WIN-I952126Q8TK","org.apache.ignite.ips":"10.239.102.144, fe80:0:0:0:4d4b:58b8:6418:3853%eth1","path.separator":";","os.version":"10.0","java.endorsed.dirs":"C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.265.01-hotspot\jre\lib\endorsed","org.apache.ignite.rest.tcp.addrs":["127.0.0.1","0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1","10.239.102.144"],"ERLANG_HOME":"C:\Program Files\erl-23.0","java.runtime.name":"OpenJDK Runtime Environment","org.apache.ignite.ignite.dep.mode":{},"java.vm.name":"OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM","org.apache.ignite.ignite.name":"DXTApacheIgnite","org.apache.ignite.authentication.enabled":false,"org.apache.ignite.jvm.pid":6640,"LocalDeploymentSpi.org.apache.ignite.spi.class":"org.apache.ignite.spi.deployment.local.LocalDeploymentSpi","comm.direct.proto.ver":3,"TcpCommunicationSpi.org.apache.ignite.spi.class":"org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi","CommonProgramFiles":"C:\Program Files\Common Files","java.vendor.url.bug":"http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/","org.apache.ignite.rest.port.range":100,"org.apache.ignite.offheap.size":1822762598,"OS":"Windows_NT","org.apache.ignite.marshaller.useDefaultSUID":false,"user.dir":"C:\Users\DXT\Desktop\Release","org.apache.ignite.restart.enabled":"false","os.arch":"amd64","PROCESSOR_REVISION":"4f01","CommonProgramW6432":"C:\Program Files\Common Files","AlwaysFailoverSpi.org.apache.ignite.spi.class":"org.apache.ignite.spi.failover.always.AlwaysFailoverSpi","TcpCommunicationSpi.comm.tcp.pairedConnection":false,"RoundRobinLoadBalancingSpi.org.apache.ignite.spi.class":"org.apache.ignite.spi.loadbalancing.roundrobin.RoundRobinLoadBalancingSpi","SystemRoot":"C:\Windows","TEMP":"C:\Users\DXT\AppData\Local\Temp","java.vm.info":"mixed mode","USERPROFILE":"C:\Users\DXT","java.vm.version":"25.265-b01","TMP":"C:\Users\DXT\AppData\Local\Temp","TcpCommunicationSpi.comm.tcp.port":47100,"clientListenerPort":10800,"CommonProgramFiles(x86)":"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files","java.ext.dirs":"C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.265.01-hotspot\jre\lib\ext;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\lib\ext","java.class.version":"52.0","org.apache.ignite.marshaller":"org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryMarshaller"}

Comment: Can you share full logs from both nodes? Also, what does systemStartupHelper.GetRegisteredInstances() return?

Comment: Hello, I've update the post

Comment: this log doesn't have anything useful. Can you upload full log files somewhere?